# how to make javascript rearrangeable windows?

Tags: javascript, floating, panels

I want to make a web page with several type of forms,each one on a different area that allows those areas to be rearranged and user will be able to change their position according to their preference.(X form to the left top, Y form to the right bottom etc.) i don't know what that type of windows are called, but think you can get a idea what I'm mentioning here.only thing i know is it can be achieved with javascript, i searched for it but i can't find the relevant tutorial or guide to self study. 
some one please tell me what they are, and how to make them and include in my web page? is there any thing that ease of making those thing except javascript?please provide me a source of studying and i really appreciate the instructions of the knowledged people.thanks in advance!

regards,
rangana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nutshell version is that you wait for a mousedown event, store information about where the click started and where the element started, wait for a mousemove event and change those positions, then wait for a mouseup event to clean up afterwards.

Usually, this is best achieved by just using a library such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/dragdrop/) or [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable)

Comment: Rather that using the events, you can have a working solution like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: … which uses those events. I did suggest using a library.